# Haskell: Regular Expressions and Data.Text

Tags: regex, haskell, text

When processing large amounts of textual data, it is recommended to use `Data.Text` instead of haskells native strings. Check, done. But how about regular expressions? Is there a regex library available, specialized on `Data.Text`? As far as I can see, all regular expression libraries are working on Haskell native Strings or even worse CStrings.

Comment: Keep in mind that given the ease of writing parsers (literally dozens of packages) in Haskell, regexes aren't actually very common in most idiomatic Haskell code. Parsers tend to be more legible (you name productions, etc.), more maintainable, and aren't necessarily all that much slower.

Comment: Did you tried Text.Regex.TDFA [http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa] ? I find it enough fast but do not know what means *large amount* of data in your case. I'd also agree with @copumpkin parsers like Text.Parsec are more suitable in most of situations.

Comment: specifically see the text version too: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa-text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Data.Text [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.0/doc/html/Data-Text.html):

> To use an extended and very rich family of functions for working with
> Unicode text (including normalization, **regular expressions**,
> non-standard encodings, text breaking, and locales), see the text-icu
> package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu

More precisely [Data.Text.ICU.Regex](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text-icu/0.6.3.5/doc/html/Data-Text-ICU-Regex.html)

Answer (score 0):

[regex-tdfa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa) offers a `Text`-based interface in the `Text.Regex.TDFA.Text` module. Its advantage over the `text-icu` package is that it doesn't use the `IO` monad, so it's easier to use.

Answer (score -1):

**Regular Expression Ecosystem and Haskell**

Regexes are a tool that people migrating from other languages just kind of expect to be one of the tools available in the language.  In compiled languages this functionality tends come in the form of libraries like [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/). Scripting languages often have Regexs built right into the language, but under the hood the interpreter is using one of these same libraries.

There is a good reason for this. Finite State Automata are rather arcane, somewhat tedious to implement, and hard to make efficient.  Why reinvent the wheel?

So what is wrong with Haskell? Well, these well known libraries all work on arrays of 8 bit words terminated by a `NUL` byte -- a `CString` in Haskell nomenclature.  Regular strings in Haskell are lists of [Char](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Char). (quite literally: `type String = [Char]`).  That causes two problems: 1) a char is a single *unicode* character, not an 8 bit byte.  (GHC stores Char as UTF16 internally) and 2) a list is not an array.  This means that if we want to do Regex in Haskell we either need to convert our text into a CStiring and make a foreign call to something like PCRE or implement an efficient Finite State Automata and [regex parser natively](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.95.1/docs/Text-Regex.html).

Converting unicode to ascii is a lossy and risky operation.  Some libraries make some assumptions about the string they are working on and do the conversion for you, others make you build the CString for them so you can figure out what to do when a [`☃`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2603/index.htm) shows up in tour text.

So then what about `Data.Text`? Well it is at least an array, but internally it is a UTF16 array.  It is still possible to convert to an 8 bit CString, but not with any great efficiency.  There is also the possibility of using a unicode aware regex engine.  [International Components for Unicode (ICU)](http://site.icu-project.org/) has [such a library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) and there is a binding to it in the [text-icu](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu) package.  The very nature of Unicode means that this package is less efficient then PCRE so some people prefer to still use bindings to the latter. You will have to decide what your preference it based on what you are using regexes for.